# Where exactly are the Ramayana & Mahabharata scripts preserved?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, ramayana, belief

As we all know Ramayana was written by Valmiki Maharshi and Mahabharata was written by Veda Vyasa. Some say that Veda Vyasa narrated the Mahabharata story to Lord Ganesha who wrote it. Is that true?

Also, scientifically, where exactly are the Ramayana and Mahabharata scripts (in written form) believed to exist? I know there are lots of evidence like stones, places etc., but I want to know about the actual scripts. Are they in any museum or some other place?

I am very eager to know this.

Comment: The Ramayana and Mahabharata were both passed down via oral tradition initially, and only passed down in written form much later.  The manuscript written by Ganesha is not how the Mahabharata was actually passed down, but in any case I'm not sure what happened to that manuscript.

Comment: May I know the reason for down voting this question?

Comment: There's a similar question here with an answer: [Original Ramayana and Mahabharata](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6627/2995)