# Where is Bhagavad Gita referred to as Hari Gita?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, reference-request

I heard that Bhagavad Gita is referred to as Hari Gita. I don't know the exact reference. Where is it referred as Hari Gita?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhagavad_Gita   **The Bhagavad Gita (sometimes Bhagavadgita) is also known as the Isvara Gita, the Ananta Gita, the Hari Gita, the Vyasa Gita, or simply as the Gita.[21]** You can check the reference. I know Shankara calls it as Ishwara gita at one place in one of his works.

Comment: @LazyLubber I don't know who down votes even these type of questions. For few of my answers, I can understand the down votes... But, many of my questions are unnecessarily down voted..

Comment: I think I understand why this is downvoted. (I did not downvote it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hari gita is another term used for Bhagavad gita which is referred in the section CCCXLIX of Shanti Parva in Mahabharata. From [Keshav Srinivasan's answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6631/6981):

> In the beginning of the Treta Yuga, Vivaswat imparted the knowledge of this cult to Manu. Manu, for the protection and support of all the worlds, then gave it to his son Ikshaku. 2 Promulgated by Ikshaku, that cult over-spreads the whole world. When the universal destruction comes, it will once more return to Narayana and be merged in Him. The religion which is followed and practised by the Yatis, has, **O best of kings, been narrated to thee before this in the Hari Gita, with all its ordinances in brief.**

Comment: Super excellent answer.