# Why is Mahabharata called Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata

Mahabharata was initially called Jaya which means victory. But then it was called Bharata.

Why is Mahabharata called Mahabharata?

Comment: Is your account hacked?

Comment: Mahabharata is called so because it is GREAT.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Original Ramayana and Mahabharata](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6627/original-ramayana-and-mahabharata)

Answer (score 4):

`Mahatvaat Bharavatvaat Cha MahaBharatam` - **Mahat** - Big/Important. **Bharam** - Heavy/Deep

Since it is important and deep (in spiritual knowledge), it is called Mahabharatam

`SaPaada Laksha Grantham` - **1.25 lakh** shlokas

`Bharatah Panchamo Vedah` - Bharata is **5th Veda**

Raja **Bharata**, upon whom India (Bharat) is named, was one of the previous ancestors/kings of the Kuru race, who later fought in Mahabharat war, which was a **World War** 5000 years ago, with 18 Akshauhinis (~**40 lakh soldiers**) dying on battlefield.

(I don't know which scripture these phrases occur in. I have heard them used in traditional Upanyas/Pravachan)

Answer (score 2):

Mahabharata was initially called **Jayasamhita** written by Ganesha and narrated by Vyasa.

> Om! Having bowed down to Narayana and Nara, the most exalted male being, and also to the goddess Saraswati, must the word Jaya be uttered.

After that it was narrated by Vaishampayan to King Janmajaya and was called **Bharata.**

> We are desirous of hearing that history also called **Bharata**, the holy composition of the wonderful Vyasa, which dispelleth the fear of evil, just as it was cheerfully recited by the **Rishi Vaisampayana, under the direction of Dwaipayana himself, at the snake-sacrifice of Raja Janamejaya?**

After some times, gods measured the knowledge of Vedas and Bharata in which Bharata overweighted Vedas. Hence onwards it was called **Mahabharata (The great Bharata).**

> In former days, having placed the four Vedas on one side and the Bharata on the other, these were weighed in the balance by the celestials assembled for that purpose. **And as the latter weighed heavier than the four Vedas with their mysteries, from that period it hath been called in the world Mahabharata (the great Bharata).**

[Adi Parva Section 1](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01002.htm)