# Why do some Hindus say "ram ram" twice?

Tags: belief, rama

Why do some Hindus say **"ram ram"** twice? why not only once like **"ram"** or thrice like **"ram ram ram"**? What is the actual reason behind that?

Comment: Before writing Ramayana Rishi Valmiki was a thief and pirate named as " Valiya lutera". Sage Narada suggested him to chant Mara Mara whose opposite is Rama Rama. Valmiki started and he became sage out of the pirate and Lord Rama blessed him to write Ramayana.

It is truth that by chanting name of Rama everything can be accomplished. http://www.hinduismfacts.org/2012/03/why-do-hindus-say-ram-ram/

Comment: Do you mean when they meet?

Comment: @CR241 was it Rama or Brahma who gave blessings to Valmiki? According to this that was Brahma [link](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/757/how-could-valmiki-write-the-ramayana)

Comment: There is no hard-and-fast rule behind this, and many people say 'hey ram', or 'jai sri ram', or 'sri ram jaya ram'..  
Why do people say 'bye-bye' twice instead of bye ? or bye-bye-bye ?

Comment: This is no hard rule for this. Many Hindus say this. Like, "Rama Rama", "Hari. Hari", "Shiva Shiva". Even Narada muni always says "Narayana Narayana twice".

Comment: Because you greet the Ram in you and in the other person.

Answer (score 3):

Certain sounds are associated with some vibrations which enhance the functioning of Chakras of body.

The following text was taken from [this link](http://sciencebehindmantras.blogspot.in/2013/01/beej-mantras.html):

> For example, Ram is the mantra for manipura chakra (navel centre) and if it 
>   is chanted in kirtan or repeated in japa, it will stimulate the abdominal 
>   area benefiting complaints such as peptic ulcer, constipation, diarrhoea and other digestive disorders.
>
> Mantras Chakra Physical location
>    Lam Mooladhara Perineum
>    Vam Swadhisthana Base of the spine 
>    Ram Manipura Navel centre
>    Yam Anahata Heart centre 
>    Ham Vishudhi Throat
>    Om Ajna Eyebrow centre

Comment: It is [रं for Manipura Chakra not राम](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/13742/3500) (Sanskit sounds not Hindi sounds).

Comment: If Rama helps in peptic ulcer(following your theory), why not Ham or Yam because heart is also important. Heart is the most important organ of our body. Isn't it? Then why don't people say Yam Yam?

Comment: @Sinister That sound is ram not Rama. Since Hindi users speak Rama as Ram, Op thought it had connection to Rama Nama Japa.

Comment: I do not see an answer to the question.

Answer (score 3):

परवंदन कालेषु रामरामेति सर्वदा।

शुद्रा वदन्तु सर्वत्र तेन् तेषां गतिर् भवेत्।।

(Anand ramayan rajya khand 10.114)

Shri Ramchandra says:- whenever wherever people will salute others by saying "ram ram", I myself will give salvation to them

That's why people had been saying "ram ram" from treta yug to present.

Comment: Niroj Ji please answer this question. I have had this doubt for quite some time now. I have posted links of different Saints' advice   https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/56383/what-to-chant-as-nama-japa-sita-rama-or-just-rama

Comment: Its said in lomesh samhita, that result of one chant of sita is equivalent to result of crores times chant of ram. So chanting Sita Ram is not equivalent to chanting of ram naam. Hope my reply will clear your doubts

Comment: Sir can you tell me the verse number? I found one online edition of Lomesh Samhita and it does praise name of Lord Rama...but I want to read the exact verse. Also, Can we chant both names? Because it is generally said by saints to focus on one Nama. Can we chant Sita Rama and Rama alternatively? Do we earn the same merits. Please answer on the now reopened question so others can benefit aswell. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/56383/is-nama-japa-of-both-sita-rama-and-rama-equivalent-when-it-comes-to-spiritual-me

Comment: Lomesh samhita actually has 24 chapters . Chapter 2-10 deals with astrology. After chapter 10, the part is missing. But acharyas of shri Ramananda sampradaye have some naam mahima from missing chapters. So the latter half of book is extinct.

Comment: So today I have fever, so whenever I get healthy, I will give answer with proof

Comment: No worries. Please look after your health and get well soon.

Answer (score 1):

For marathi people *"Ram Ram"* was Started by **Samartha Ramdas** in 1600. You can find the discription of these things in  **Dasabodha** which is written by **Swami Ramdas**.So Whenever two person meet they greet as  *"Ram Ram"*.

Comment: Yes the question why ram ram why not ram ram ram or only ram

Answer (score 0):

Saying Ram Ram twice has same effects as counting beads 108 times. Saying Ram once has benefits of counting mala 54 times. Saying Ram Ram does not effect one chakra alone instead, it effects all the chakras including chitta which is outside the physical body.

Comment: Do you have any scriptual evidence for this?

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange! In order to maintain some quality standards, [We insist](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/803/277) on citing some sources while answering question, in other words, backing up answers with authoritative texts. You should cite some [reliable](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/277) sources. You may refer [resources](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15425) to find and get popular useful scriptures.

Comment: Hell! Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange. As others have commented, we have a policy of requiring sources in answers. There can be any reference. See [answer] and take a [tour] to know difference between regular Hinduism forums and our site. Write answers such that they don't require further clarification from the author of the post.

Answer (score 0):

The question is

> Why do some Hindus say "ram ram" twice?

There is a reason for saying **ram**, some may say twice.

---

The ultimate aim of any scripture related to the God is to goad the  people towards the God/Spirituality/SELF REALISATION.

Achieving spirituality is easier said than done.  Even persons with track record of doing austerities with sincerity and commitment often slip back due to the power of senses.

Then what about ordinary people?

---

Sri Krishna says

> Those who relinquish the body while remembering Me at the moment of
>   death will come to Me. There is certainly no doubt about this.
>   (Bhagavad Gita 8.5).

Here, we should not confuse ourselves with the notion that it is the form/name of Sri Krishna alone that gives liberation.

At the time of uttering those words, the mind of Sri Krishna had merged into the BRAHMAN/GOD, and thus those were the generalised utterances, ie., any form/name of the God.

---

However, human nature/prArabdha will not allow one to remember the name of the God at the deathbed [unless practised for long](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/37254/3869).

The sages/ancient of the earlier era, found some subtle techniques in goading people towards spirituality. The following are some of such simple but subtle techniques, which will make them remember the name of the God, **at least occasionally**.

---

1. Doing bhajans on auspicious days like birth days of Krishna, Rama or Shiva Ratri or Dussehra, etc
2. Fasting on ekAdasi or in the month of kArtika, simultaneously remembering the name of the God or doing pArAyana of a text of his/her choice
3. Greeting other persons with the name of God.  Easiest name of the God that can be used is **Ram**. Some may be saying Sri Rama.
4. Even in funeral procession, the name of the Sri Ram will be chanted in some areas, in a different way, to indicate that only the **God is the Ultimate/TRUTH**, but not the mortal body - **rAm nAm satya hai**.

---

In many of the families in our area, including myself, people say whenever start doing something anew, we will **write or utter the name of Sri Rama** and start the listing of issues.

It is not restricted to Hinduism alone.  Even Muslims say **[Wa alaykumu s-salam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wa_alaykumu_s-salam)**, indicating **May the peace and mercy of Allah be with you too**.

Comment: This does not make sense: one could argue that saying ram would be sufficient.