# Does Bhagvad Gita 8.5 and 8.6 say that karma can be overcome at time of death?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, karma

This is what BG 8.5 and 8.6 say

> Bhagavad Gita 8.5 Those who relinquish the body while remembering Me at the moment of death will come to Me. There is certainly no doubt about this.
>
> Bhagavad Gita 8.6 Whatever one remembers upon giving up the body at the time of death, O son of Kunti, one attains that state, being always absorbed in such contemplation.

Does it mean a lifetime of wrong karma will be forgotten if one remembers God at time of death ?

Please note I am not delving into how lifetime preparation is required to remember God at time of death. Just seeing if this is a shortcut

Scripture references would be helpful if the answer is No.

Comment: The statement could be arthavAda. It could be meant for encouraging people to remember God always.

Comment: Well i would say if one can perform this impossible feat of remembering God at the time of death being sinned all his life, that person deserves to be liberated :)
Bhakti can destroy prArabdha karma as well, so in a sense yes this is the shortcut but is impossible for one who is not practicing to achieve it. And yes this is like the final test for any human being to get liberated, so if one has not studied the whole year how can he write an exam and hope of passing?

Comment: @Prakash K "Bhakti can destroy prArabdha karma". I knew that jnAna can destroy karma. But how can bhakti destroy karma, that too prArabdha karma? Could you please explain?

Comment: @Iwillcloseyourquestion Nice username! I was a little afraid at first to answer your comment, lest you close all my questions :-D. Anyways to answer your question, according to padma-purana it clearly states:
aprārabdha-phalaṁ pāpaṁ
kūṭaṁ bījaṁ phalonmukham
krameṇaiva pralīyeta
viṣṇu-bhakti-ratātmanām
For those who are engaged in the devotional service of Lord Vishnu, all sinful reactions, whether fructified (prArabdha/phalonmukham), not fructified (aprArabdha), kutam or in the form of a seed (bijam), gradually vanish.

Comment: @PrakashK Thanks for responding. I might ask a question on this topic in the near future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is

> Does it mean a lifetime of wrong karma will be forgotten if one
> remembers God at time of death ?

---

My answer is NO.

The Ultimate purpose of any scripture will be to goad humans towards spirituality, which will liberate one from the clutches of cycle of births.

[prArabdha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prarabdha_karma#Primary_literature), be it results in ***transient*** happiness or sorrow,  has to be enjoyed.

> आत्मानं सततं ज्ञात्वा कालं नय महामते | प्रारब्धमखिलं भुञ्जन्नोद्वेगं
> कर्तुमर्हसि || २१||
>
> 21. O intelligent man, spend your life always in the knowing of the supreme bliss, enjoying the whole of your prArabdha (that portion of
>     past Karma now being enjoyed) without making any complaint (of it).

---

Further, sloka 8.14 should be read together with the above 2 slokas, i.e., 8.5 & 8.6 to understand this issue.

> अनन्यचेताः सततं यो मां स्मरति नित्यशः।
>
> तस्याहं सुलभः पार्थ नित्ययुक्तस्य योगिनः।।8.14।।
>
> And whosoever constantly bears Me in mind never attached to any other
> object-for this Yogin, ever devout, I am easy to attain, O son of
> Prtha !

***So attaining liberation/moksha is possible only if, I repeat, only if ONE who constantly remembers the God, but not at the time of death alone.***

Comment: Ajamila spent his entire life committing sins and not remembering God. Yet, at the time of his death, when he chanted "Narayana" unintentionally, he attained moksha.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury He did not attain moksha immediately, if I remember it right. He was given a second chance.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury: I know that story, but it contradicts the concept of prArabdha.  Further, Sages like Sri Ramana Maharshi stressed on undergoing the Karma

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury: I agree with (Lazy Lubber).  In the story of Ajamila, he was given a 2nd chance, to recify his deeds.

Comment: Well, in the Bhagavatam story, Narayana's servants stopped Yama's servants from taking him away and explicitly stated that his chanting expiated all his sins. And I'm guessing by second chance, you mean him performing Vairagya near the Ganges after this incident. @LazyLubber

Comment: @srimannaryana k v - how about 8.13? "One who departs from the body while remembering Me, the Supreme Personality, and chanting the syllable Om, will attain the supreme goal."

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury By second chance, I mean that he was not immediately given moksha or death, but was given another chance at life.

Comment: @Carmensandiego These statements could be eulogies. They have 2 purposes - to glorify God and Om, and to encourage people to remember God always.

Comment: **One who departs from the body while remembering Me....**, does indicate action already started much before that but not alone at that time. @Carmen sandiego

Comment: @srimannarayana k  - Any reason as to why the final moments are emphasized in the 3 slokas - 8.5,8.6 and 8.13. I mean wasn't 8.14 enough to drive home the point which is to remember God always.

Comment: @Lazy Lubber - Your input in above comment will also be helpful

Comment: Except 8.6 , the remaining three Slokas in question - 8.5, 8.13 and 8.14 - indicate/lay stress on the same issue- remember God all the time. The sloka hints subtly about the danger of falling back into the Loop of birth and death, if one concentrates on material issues at the time of death. The story of [Jada Bharata](https://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/vivekananda/volume_4/lectures_and_discourses/the_story_of_jada_bharata.htm) is a lesson for all  @Carmen sandiego

Comment: "The Ultimate purpose of any scripture will be to goad humans towards spirituality.." Agreed.

Comment: @srimannaraya k - I am inclined to accept the answer. Just one last incidental question on purpose of scriptures - do tantras also guide towards spirituality?

Comment: Yes, if properly utilised. Sri Ramakrishna paramhansa told to avoid tantric method, as that is fraught with problems.@Carmen sandiego