# Does any scripture say that chanting the name of a god exactly three times at the time of death yields Moksha?

Tags: gods, belief, moksha

In one of the comments in an answer on this site, I read this assertion that if the name of God is chanted **three times exactly** at the time of death, the jivātman will attain Moksha.

[Here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3563/who-gives-moksha/48801#comment7752_3573)

> Yes. **It is said to one who repeats God's name 3 times at the time of death gains liberation**. Krishna says (Gita 8.5) "And whoso at the time of death, leaves his body thinking of Me alone and goes forth--he attains My being; concerning this there is no doubt."

So, does this 'three-times chanting' assertion finds an explicit mention in any text?

Which Purāṇas or other canonical text says so?

I'm specifically asking about the claim of chanting the name exactly three times at the time of death, and not in any other way whatsoever.

---

Related to, but not duplicate of:

- [Who gives Moksha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3563/who-gives-moksha/48801#48801)
- [Does Bhagvad Gita 8.5 and 8.6 say that karma can be overcome at time of death?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/37251/does-bhagvad-gita-8-5-and-8-6-say-that-karma-can-be-overcome-at-time-of-death)
- [Which Scriptures say that by chanting Lord's name during the time of one's death one can attain "Moksha"?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16028/which-scriptures-say-that-by-chanting-lords-name-during-the-time-of-ones-death)

Comment: Any karma , including upasana ( manasika karma) or chanting Ishwaras name 3 times etc yield a karma phala Viz. uthpathi , Aapthi Vikruthi, samskruthi ( upadesha sahasri chapter 17 verse 50), Moksha is chaturvidha phala vilakshanam.Jnanam and Jnana nishta is moksha which require nidhidhyasanam. as in dasha shloki Na bhoomir Na yagnam.Na theertham Na varnashramachara dharma .. shivakevaloham

Comment: But, it doesn't say '3 times before death'. @Athrey

Comment: Jnana(Moksha from samsara) cannot be a direct effect / consequence of any kayaka karma or manasika  karma   ,though it could be the stepping stone for moksha(krama mukti). Chanting a nama thrice falls under karma,whose  phala could be a loka(Lokyate anubhuyate iti lokaha)
For one who is not a Jnani, the final frame of mind could fetch a karma phala of a loka (tad bhava bhavithaha  BG 8.6)
sa-roopam, sameepyam, salokam of the lord . Shankaracharya cleary states both vaikundam and kailasham praapthi  is not moksham.